# react-hooks query and setState causes 500 error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client, react-functional-component

I think this could be a bug or a misconfiguration. 
I get this error: 
`networkError: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 500`

Submitting the form the first time I would get the desired result, but if I hit the submit button again, I get the networkError message above.

```
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const [val, setValu] = useState({
    email: 'example@example.com',
    password: 'password',
    texterror: {
      status: false,
      text: ''
    },
  })


//the submit function below: 

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await client.query({
      query: Handle_Login, 
      variables: {
        email: val.email, 
        password: val.password
      }
    }).then((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    }).catch((e) => {
      setValu({
        texterror: {
          status: true, 
          text: 'it be broke yo'
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

However, if I remove `setValu({texterror: {status: true, text: 'it be broke yo'}})` in the catch, The 500 error goes away. I could spam the submit button and I wouldn't receive the 500 error.

For right now I'm going to not have a setState inside just to avoid this problem, but I would like to know if there is a solution to this issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you say the error goes away, do you mean it does not error at all, even in your network tab? Or do you mean it simply does not show in your state?

Comment: @TeeJ  Sorry, I should have been more clear about that. When I remove the setValu  in the catch and replace it with just  a normal console.log() there is no 500 error. If I keep the setValu in the catch, the first submit is successful, but if I press submit again, I get the 500 error.

Comment: That's because you then don't have a username and password. console.log val over both requests to confirm but that should help.

Comment: Ok....... 

You're right. I put setValu({
email: 'example@example.com',
password: 'password', 
texterror: { status: true, text: 'text'}
})

and that worked. thank you so much! you should put it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you for helping me with this issue that has been bugging me for hours!

Comment: Added it as an answer for any future readers. Glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top level, it's clear that you're causing some kind of error on the server side. A `500` code means there is an "internal server error". So you should really look at your server code and figure out how to safeguard against unexpected input so that it won't error and/or crash but instead return code `400` which is "bad request".

So the question becomes, what about your frontend code is causing a malformed server request?

I suspect that you're trying to use `setValu()` (which is a React hook) the same way one might use a traditional `setState` call in a class component. However, they behave quite differently.

In a class component, `setState` performs a "shallow merge" of the old state and the new state. So if you did:

```
setState({
  texterror: {
    status: true, 
    text: 'it be broke yo'
  }
});
```

If would find only the field `texterror` on the state object and update that.

However, React hooks work differently. `useState()` creates a single atomic value, and when you call `setValu()` it *complete replaces the previous value* stored in `val`.

So:

```
  const [val, setValu] = useState({
    email: 'example@example.com',
    password: 'password',
    texterror: {
      status: false,
      text: ''
    },
  });

  // val is now an object with 'email', 'password', and 'texterror' fields


  setValu({
    texterror: {
      status: true, 
      text: 'it be broke yo'
    }
  });

  // val is now an object with only a 'texterror' field
```

In your code when you are using `setValu` you are wholly replacing the value of `val` to something that doesn't have an email or password field, which when sent to the server causes an internal server error. A simple fix would be to simply merge the old value of `val` with the desired new object when you update it:

```
  setValu({
    ...val,
    texterror: {
      status: true, 
      text: 'it be broke yo'
    }
  });
```

Comment: That makes total sense and thank you so much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that with the useState hook you  are overwriting the entire state val. This means that you have no longer got a email and password. It is a common oversight when moving from class based components to hooks. Add the parts of the state that didn't change too, and it should all work again.